# Gradient Animation - Slow down and speed up

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-animation, cagradientlayer

I'm animating a `CAGradientLayer`, similar to how Apple did with their "Slide to Unlock" animation on the home screen of iPhone. However my animation is a little different in that it slows down and speeds up at certain points.

The code I have so far is animates a gradient and works, but how would I get it to slow down/speed up at different points?

```
class AnimatedMaskLabel: UIView {

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        // Configure the gradient here
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

        let colors = [
            UIColor.black.cgColor,
            UIColor.white.cgColor,
            UIColor.black.cgColor
        ]
        gradientLayer.colors = colors

        let locations: [NSNumber] = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.locations = locations

        return gradientLayer
    }()

  @IBInspectable var text: String! {
    didSet {
      setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
  }

  override func didMoveToWindow() {
    super.didMoveToWindow()

    layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

    let gradientAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
    gradientAnimation.fromValue = [0.0, 0.0, 0.25]
    gradientAnimation.toValue = [0.75, 1.0, 1.0]
    gradientAnimation.duration = 3.0
    gradientAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    gradientLayer.add(gradientAnimation, forKey: nil)
  }

}
```

**Update 1:**

[image]

To make it look exactly like I want, would I need to use `CAMediaTimingFunction` at all?

Comment: You’re going to need a keyframe animation.

Comment: @JF How so - would I still use `CAGradientLayer` and combine that with a `CAKeyframeAnimation`?

Comment: The same way you’re using a `CABasicAnimation` now, but using a `CAKeyframeAnimation` instead.

Comment: @JF Ok, I see what you mean. I've used `CAKeyframeAnimation` before, but that was to animate a `UIView` along a given `path`. Not sure how to use it with a `CAGradientLayer `. Could you please show some code or point me to a link? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a keyframe animation, try:

```
let gradientAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
gradientAnimation.values = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.25], [0.375, 0.5, 0.625], [0.75, 1.0, 1.0]]
gradientAnimation.duration = 3.0
gradientAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
gradientLayer.add(gradientAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

This will go between the three times equally. To change the times at which the keyframes occur, set `keyTimes`:

```
gradientAnimation.keyTimes = [0.0, 0.4, 1.0]
```

This will set the percentage of the animation should be passed for each element in `values` to reflect the current state of the animation. This should also have the same length as `values`.

<sub><sup>I don’t actually know Swift, so this *should* work, but I can’t guarantee it.</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out (modified it a little) and just updated my code. I have one further question above regarding `CAMediaTimingFunction`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! : )

Comment: I just can't seem to tweak the values to get it perfect. Could you please look at my new question, thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032073/gradient-animation-slow-down-and-speed-up