# Gradient Animation - Slow down and speed up

Tags: ios, swift

I'm animating a CAGradientLayer, similar to how Apple did with their "Slide to Unlock" animation on the home screen of iPhone. However my animation is a little different in that it slows down and speeds up at certain points.

Any ideas on how to slow/speed up gradients?

Comment: I think it is problem of your speed and duration. Make them equal and try it. Your gardient speed adjust according to your duration

Comment: @Jecky Just tried that now, if they are equal then it either goes to fast or too slow. So 1.0 is very fast, and 2.0 is kind of slow. Still, the video above shows that it moves very slowly for almost 1 second making all the words white. Setting the speed/duration the same doesn't have this effect. I think the way I set the `gradientLayer.frame` might also be a problem

Comment: Apple's is probably a springing animation.

Comment: @matt Yeah for sure. There's actually a library that replicates Apple's with private api's: https://github.com/TimOliver/TOGlintyStringView. To be honest, mine is much more simple and that's ok

Comment: why you set x origin with -bounds.size.width ? it will be like from 0. This will start your gradient view from exa. if device is iphone 5 then your framw is like (-320 , 568 ,960, 568) please set frame of gradient layer according to your view. your frame is like (0, 0 , view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)

Comment: @Jecky This was from a tutorial, it said to set that and the width like so: "This sets the gradient frame to three times the width of the visible area. The animation enters the view, passes right through it, and exits out the right hand side." Basically, it makes the gradient larger so it spreads out more.

Comment: Though it is from tutorial, set your desired frame for gradient layer

Comment: @Jecky Weird, If I set the frame that way, nothing appears on screen, not sure why

Comment: @matt Any thoughts on this? Thanks

Comment: @JEL this is a very interesting question but please don't re-ask the same question twice.

Comment: @matt Sure thing, any way to delete it at this point?

Comment: I don't think it's a big deal at this point; just a general rule to know in future.

Answer (score 2):

Most often, in animation software, this effect is not created by animating the gradient's colour positions, but by moving the entire gradient underneath the text, treating the text as a mask. This is, generally speaking, more efficient, because redrawing a gradient is expensive.

This means drawing the gradient into a material (context) and then rendering that out to an image, and moving the image underneath your text, whilst the text masks out that image. In the tradition of gaming, using two of the images, so they scroll perfectly and seamless gives you the right effect.

Then you simply speed up or slow down the positional animations of the images that are your gradients.

I hope this is of some help... despite being a ways off the way you're doing things now.

Here's a little blog post on using CATextLayers as a mask: https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/245-masking-views-with-text-using-catextlayer

Here's the animation curve for position, to get the result you want:

[image]

Which creates this result:

[image]

### UPDATE:

This is what it looks like mechanically, with a "hole" of the text cut out of the surface material, and a gradient texture passing underneath, with the animation curve shown in the above screen shot:

[image]

Comment: That looks really good. Notice how the animation in my question still shows the text in light gray even when the white part is not over it. Yours is completely black when the white part is gone. Do you think it's possible to have the text gray? Is this actual code you wrote to make that effect, if so can you share please? Thanks

Comment: No, this is not code, I just showed that a "texture" of gradient does exactly as you want... minus the grey. To achieve that dark grey lettering, simply end the gradient at the dark grey of your choice, and make the background a dark grey, too.

Comment: Just did some research, it seems from what you said and what I read, that to get this effect you have 1 image and some text as the mask. The image would be the background. Is it best to just get this from my designer or do I have to create it in code? Also there is this library from link you gave: https://github.com/Ekhoo/Translucid.

Comment: See update. It's a lot simpler than the way you were doing things. Just animate the texture moving underneath the masked foreground "text" layer.

Comment: That helps a lot. So instead of animating the gradient locations, I animate the entire gradient (and I can create this gradient in code with `CAGradientLayer`). In order to make the text gray, and not completely clear when white is not over it, I would have the gradient longer with the edges gray (If I understand correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pause (or delay) between each animation? Try a variation on this between your code in didMoveToWindow():

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
        deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
}
```

Comment: Hm, not sure how I would delay it... I'll look into it